# Repeated string values needs to be separated

Tags: javascript

How Do i split `abcabc` as `abc` in Javascript .

Note: `abcabc` can be any string but the pattern will be like `bacbac`, `defdef`, `namename`, `BallBall`

Comment: Can you include more data?  What happens to the string if it doesn't match?

Comment: could it have more than one repetition? or zero? what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is always two words of the same length:

```js
let s = 'abcabc'
console.log(s.slice(0, s.length/2));
```

Comment: Pattern need not to be of constant length. Let OP confine the problem and his work.

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam What do you mean "of constant length"?

Comment: @JoeIddon I think they mean there could be more than two words, and the OP hasn't been fully clear as to whether it is restricted to two or can be more than two.

Comment: @DKyleo Ok, guess we'll wait and see

Comment: It is fine for me

Answer (score 2):

You could split the array by using a lazy quantifier and a positive lookahead for the last pattern and a filterign for empty strings.

```js
var string = 'ababab',
    array = string.split(/(.+?)(?=\1)/).filter(Boolean);
    
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just divide the string in half:

```js
function inHalf(str) {
  let middle = Math.ceil(str.length / 2);
  return str.slice(0, middle);
}

console.log(inHalf("abcabc"))
console.log(inHalf("bacbac"))
console.log(inHalf("somethingsomething"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want replace all occurrences of words which are "mirror images" of each other, then try this option:

```js
var string = "Hello abcabc world defgdefg blah blah";
console.log(string.replace(/\b(.*)\1\b/mg, "$1"));
```

A mirror image word can be matched using the following pattern:

```
\b(.*)\1\b
```

This will match some quantity, precisely half of a word, followed by the same sequence in the second half.  Then, we can replace this with just one half of the mirror word.